# script_score not works on ElasticSearch 7

Tags: elasticsearch

I upgraded my ES from 2.1 to 7.10, when I tried to use the same query way to search, it always show

```json
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "query_shard_exception",
                "reason": "script_score: the script could not be loaded",
                "index": "designs",
                "index_uuid": "jqvLIrY2TIyJU2bdAsGgkQ"
            }
        ],
        "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
        "reason": "all shards failed",
        "phase": "query",
        "grouped": true,
        "failed_shards": [
            {
                "shard": 0,
                "index": "designs",
                "node": "jkt6cdUBTKOJ_HTA83wgWQ",
                "reason": {
                    "type": "query_shard_exception",
                    "reason": "script_score: the script could not be loaded",
                    "index": "designs",
                    "index_uuid": "jqvLIrY2TIyJU2bdAsGgkQ",
                    "caused_by": {
                        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
                        "reason": "script_lang not supported [native]"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

Old query string:

```json
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 20,
  "explain": false,
  "_source": {
    "include": [
      "designId",
      "memberId",
      "isPersonalizable",
      "sellerTags",
      "products.productId",
      "products.productTypeId",
      "products.imageOneId",
      "products.imageTwoId",
      "products.hasPersonalizableSvg",
      "products.storeId"
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "_score": {}
    },
    {
      "designId": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "functions": [
        {
          "script_score": {
            "script": {
              "inline": "combined-conversion-scorer",
              "lang": "native",
              "params": {
                "query": "peanuts",
                "productTypeIds": [
                  128,
                  134,
                  755,
                  96,
                  113,
                  1230,
                  1231
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "multi_match": {
                "type": "most_fields",
                "query": "peanuts",
                "minimum_should_match": "3<75%",
                "fields": [
                  "sellerTags",
                  "sellerTags.shingles",
                  "sellerTags.stemmed",
                  "editorialTags",
                  "editorialTags.shingles",
                  "editorialTags.stemmed"
                ]
              }
            }
          ],
          "filter": [
            {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "nested": {
                      "query": {
                        "terms": {
                          "products.productTypeId": [
                            128,
                            134,
                            755,
                            96,
                            113,
                            1230,
                            1231
                          ]
                        }
                      },
                      "path": "products"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "nested": {
                      "query": {
                        "term": {
                          "products.locations": {
                            "value": "US-1"
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "path": "products"
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "must_not": [
                  {
                    "multi_match": {
                      "query": "some query",
                      "fields": [
                        "sellerTags",
                        "editorialTags"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "boost_mode": "multiply"
    }
  }
}
```

New query string:

```json
{
    "explain": true,
    "from": 0,
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "boost_mode": "multiply",
            "functions": [
                {
                    "script_score": {
                        "script": {
                            "source": "combined-conversion-scorer",
                            "lang": "native",
                            "params": {
                                "query": "peanuts"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "filter": [
                        {
                            "bool": {
                                "must": [
                                    {
                                        "nested": {
                                            "path": "products",
                                            "query": {
                                                "term": {
                                                    "products.locations": {
                                                        "value": "US-1"
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                ],
                                "must_not": [
                                    {
                                        "multi_match": {
                                            "fields": [
                                                "sellerTags",
                                                "editorialTags"
                                            ],
                                            "query": "another query"
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "multi_match": {
                                "fields": [
                                    "sellerTags",
                                    "sellerTags.shingles",
                                    "sellerTags.stemmed",
                                    "editorialTags",
                                    "editorialTags.shingles",
                                    "editorialTags.stemmed"
                                ],
                                "minimum_should_match": "3<75%",
                                "query": "peanuts",
                                "type": "most_fields"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "size": 200,
    "sort": [
        {
            "_score": {}
        },
        {
            "designId": {
                "order": "desc"
            }
        }
    ],
    "_source": {
        "includes": [
            "designId",
            "memberId",
            "isPersonalizable",
            "sellerTags",
            "products.productId",
            "products.productTypeId",
            "products.imageOneId",
            "products.imageTwoId",
            "products.hasPersonalizableSvg",
            "products.storeId"
        ]
    }
}
```

Actually I'm not sure if combined-conversion-scorer is custom script or not, I can't find it on old version by GET _scripts/combined-conversion-scorer.
How can I update my script to let it works? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`native` scripts](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/modules-scripting.html#native-java-scripts) are actually compiled Java classes bundled as plugins.

So you need to look for a JAR in your plugins folder. If you have the source files then you're good otherwise you might have to decompile it. In the end, you'll need to [recompile and rebuild the plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/7.17/plugin-authors.html) for your new ES version... or simply reimplement it in Painless.

Comment: Thank you, I can't use plugin on AWS opensearch, so I have to implement it in painless